# How to select multiple columns in df and bind under existing columns using dyplr

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 3 columns per person: ID, time (in 10 mins bins), and binsleep (whether the person is awake=0 or asleep =1). I have multiple persons but each of their 3 columns are next to the previous person, giving me a wide df format. I need to put each person underneath each other, hence I would like to select columns id,time, binsleep and move them from the right side underneath the first person, so that I end up with a long df.

This is what I have:

```
binsleep_wide <- read.csv("example_data.csv", header = TRUE, na.strings = "n/a")
binsleep_wide 
ID time binsleep ID.1 time.1 binsleep.1 ID.2 time.2 binsleep.2 ID.3 time.3 binsleep.3
1  1    0        0    2      0          1    3      0          0    4      0          1
2  1   10        0    2     10          1    3     10          0    4     10          1
3  1   20        1    2     20          1    3     20          0    4     20          1
4  1   30        1    2     30          1    3     30          0    4     30          0
5  1   40        1    2     40          1    3     40          1    4     40          0
6  1   50        0    2     50          1    3     50          1    4     50          0
```

And this is what I want:

```
    ID time binsleep
1   1    0        0
2   1   10        0
3   1   20        1
4   1   30        1
5   1   40        1
6   1   50        0
7   2    0        1
8   2   10        1
9   2   20        1
10  2   30        1
11  2   40        1
12  2   50        1
13  3    0        0
14  3   10        0
15  3   20        0
16  3   30        0
17  3   40        1
18  3   50        1
19  4    0        1
20  4   10        1
21  4   20        1
22  4   30        0
23  4   40        0
24  4   50        0
```

I tried using dplyr::gather() but the problem is that I don't have a common variable.

Comment: You can either use ```gather``` two times in succession first only on the ID columns and then on all others. Or you can use it on everything and separate the key into the variables and IDs by splitting ```ID.1``` into ```ID``` and ```1``` with ```separate()```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea can be with `split.default`. You can split every 3 columns, strip the names from their suffix and `rbind`, i.e.

```
do.call(rbind, 
    c(lapply(split.default(df, rep(seq(ncol(df) / 3), each = 3)), function(i) 
                 {names(i) <- sub('\\..*', '', names(i)); i}), 
make.row.names = FALSE))
```

which gives,

```
   ID time binsleep
1   1    0        0
2   1   10        0
3   1   20        1
4   1   30        1
5   1   40        1
6   1   50        0
7   2    0        1
8   2   10        1
9   2   20        1
10  2   30        1
11  2   40        1
12  2   50        1
13  3    0        0
14  3   10        0
15  3   20        0
16  3   30        0
17  3   40        1
18  3   50        1
19  4    0        1
20  4   10        1
21  4   20        1
22  4   30        0
23  4   40        0
24  4   50        0
```

Comment: The `patterns` function from `data.table` seems very handy here: `library(data.table); x <- c("ID", "time", "binsleep"); melt(dat, measure = patterns(paste0("^", x)), value.name = x)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
#Index to detect ids
index <- which(grepl('ID',names(df)))
#Create a list to save results
List <- list()
#Iterate
for(i in 1:length(index))
{
  List[[i]] <- df[,index[i]:(index[i]+2)]
  names(List[[i]])<-c('ID','time','binsleep')
}
#Bind
DF <- do.call(rbind,List)

   ID time binsleep
1   1    0        0
2   1   10        0
3   1   20        1
4   1   30        1
5   1   40        1
6   1   50        0
7   2    0        1
8   2   10        1
9   2   20        1
10  2   30        1
11  2   40        1
12  2   50        1
13  3    0        0
14  3   10        0
15  3   20        0
16  3   30        0
17  3   40        1
18  3   50        1
19  4    0        1
20  4   10        1
21  4   20        1
22  4   30        0
23  4   40        0
24  4   50        0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr v1.0.0, easily generalised for an arbitrary number of triplets.

```
d <- d %>% rename(ID.0=ID, time.0=time, binsleep.0=binsleep)
bind_rows(
  lapply(
    0:3, 
    function(x) {
      d %>% 
        select(ends_with(as.character(x))) %>% 
        rename_with(function(x) str_sub(x, 1, -3), everything())
    }
  )
)
# A tibble: 24 x 3
      ID  time binsleep
   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
 1     1     0        0
 2     1    10        0
 3     1    20        1
 4     1    30        1
 5     1    40        1
 6     1    50        0
 7     2     0        1
 8     2    10        1
 9     2    20        1
10     2    30        1
# … with 14 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Something fairly simple using `purrr` and `dplyr`.

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

cols <- c("ID", "time", "binsleep")

map_dfc(set_names(cols), ~ unlist(select(df_wide, starts_with(.x))))
```

This iterates over each column prefix, selects the columns, unlists them into a vector, and then binds the vectors back together into columns.